# Xamarin XAML Intellisense doesn't work for styles from other assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, intellisense, resourcedictionary, class-library

I wanted to separate my Xamarin app styling to a **separate class library** so it can be **reused in other apps** (light and dark theme, control styles, etc). However, the issue I'm running into is that when the class library is installed (via private nuget feed) and used in Xamarin apps, the **Intellisense doesn't work** for any of the style/color names.

Is there a way to fix this? How can I tell my class library that the ResourceDictionaries it contains need to be present at design time for Intellisense to work?

I've already tried tips from [this post about WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779105/xaml-intellisense-doesnt-work-for-referenced-assembly-resources) but had no luck
doing either the pack syntax for referencing the library or the `<ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>` way.

### Here's what the library looks like

MyMobileThemes.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2337" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="ControlStyles.xaml">
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="DarkTheme.xaml">
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="LightTheme.xaml">
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

LightTheme.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyMobileThemes.LightTheme"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="cButtonBackground">#c5c7c4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="cButtonText">#000</Color>

    <Color x:Key="cSecondaryButtonBackground">#303030</Color>
    <Color x:Key="cSecondaryButtonText">#ffffff</Color>

    <Color x:Key="cDisabledButtonBackground">#ddd</Color>
    <Color x:Key="cDisabledButtonText">#888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="cPressedButtonBackground">#ddd</Color>
    <Color x:Key="cPressedButtonText">#000</Color>

    <!-- Other colors go here -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

LightTheme.xaml.cs

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyMobileThemes
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LightTheme : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public LightTheme()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ControlStyles.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyMobileThemes.ControlStyles"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <!--  controls / button  -->
    <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource cButtonText}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource cButtonBackground}" />
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButton}" TargetType="Button" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

ControlStyles.xaml.cs

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyMobileThemes
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ControlStyles : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public ControlStyles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

### And here's how I'm using it in Xamarin apps

SampleApp.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyCompany.MyMobileThemes" Version="1.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2337" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

App.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="SampleApp.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:myMobileThemes="clr-namespace:MyMobileThemes;assembly=MyMobileThemes">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <myMobileThemes:LightTheme />
                <myMobileThemes:ControlStyles />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'll try your code on my side.BTW,could you please help confirm if you can manage to compile the project?

Comment: Yes, everything compiles just fine, the only problem I'm having is not intellisense for Color resources.

Comment: It looks like it's an VS Intellisense issue not on Xamarin side.

Comment: Whichever it is, I'd love to get this to work. Using the library without intellisense is very annoying.